# How to pass a Function name to a Case-Match statement in Scala

Tags: scala

I am a newbie to Scala Programmaing and trying to create a Case-Match or Switch-Case statement which inturn invokes different functions based on the input value.

For example please see the sample code snippet. Hope it explains what i intended to do

```
def getValue(x: Any):String = x match {
case "Value1"=> Function1(int)
case "Value2"=> Function2(int)
case _ => println("This is an invalid value")
}

def Function1(int) {
    Do Something
}

def Function2(int) {
    Do Something
}
```

When I give like this, I am getting an error as shown below :

```
Error:(26, 34) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
      case "Value1"=> Function1(int)
```

**Edited :**
**Modified the return type of getValue to be a "Unit" instead of "String"**. Now this error is resolved but I am getting the following error message

> Error:(26, 22) forward reference extends over definition of value
>   spark
>         case "Value1"=> Function1(int)

**Modified code snippet**

```
def getValue(x: Any):Unit = x match {
case "Value1"=> Function1(int)
case "Value2"=> Function2(int)
case _ => println("This is an invalid value")
}

def Function1(int) {
    Do Something
}

def Function2(int) {
    Do Something
}
```

I resolved this error by keeping the declaration of spark variable at the end of the code.

Comment: What's the relationship to Apache Spark in this question?

Comment: There is no way `case _ => println(..)` could match the expected `: String` return type

Comment: @AKSW I assumed I have to tag Apache Spark as well whenever I ask question related to Scala. Apologies if I am wrong

Comment: @cchantep Thanks for your response. It was just like a pseudocode. Not the actual code. I just described what I intended to do. Any help on how to pass a string when no condition matches will be more useful to me.

Comment: Why post pseudo-code when you can post real (but super-simplified) code? Anyway, I cleaned up the pseudo parts and your code compiles without error; a warning or two, but no errors.

Comment: @JKC Scala is a programming language, Apache Spark is a distributed processing framework. If you have a Scala question, there is obviously no need to tag it with Spark. Use the Spark tag when you have some questions regarding Spark related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `Function1` and `Function2` (horrible names!) return `Unit`, and `getValue` is declared to return a `String`

A declaration of a function looks like `def functionName(args): ReturnType = { ... }`

Some parts of this can be omitted, and then defaults are assumed. 
In your case, you omitted the `ReturnType` declaration, and (more importantly) the `=` sign. When there is no `=` before the function body, the function will always return `Unit`. If you want it to return a `String`, you need to add an `=` before the body, and make sure that the last statement in the body is indeed a `String`.

Additionally, the default `case` clause does not return anything. This does not work, because, again, `getValue` is declared to return a `String`. You need to either throw an exception in that case, or think of a default value to return (empty string?) or else use `Options`, like the other answer suggests.

Comment: Hi @Dima. Thanks for your valuable response. My function should not return strings. It should perform some operation. My question here is how to navigate to particular function body based on the input value which will be a string value. My requirement is I have to pass this string in case match statements and then it should take me to particular function body. I have modified getValue definition to return a Unit. Still it is not working properly. Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Function1 and Function2 should return strings. Also, you cannot use println, since the result of it is Unit, in this case, you can throw an exception:

```
  def getValue(x: Any):Unit = x match {
    case "Value1"=> function1(1)
    case "Value2"=> function2(2)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is an invalid value")
  }

  def function1(v: Int): String = {
      // SOME STUF THAT RETURNS STRING
  }

  def function2(v: Int): String = {
     // SOME STUF THAT RETURNS STRING
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . Function1 and Function2 should not return strings. It should perform few functions.